# Polymer UI data binding doesn't refresh

Tags: function, callback, polymer

Hi I'm working on a new project with Polyner. I made a new polymer templates for my cards. When I make a new Search I use the following search function.

```
Polymer('moviegrep-element', {
  search: function() {
    var searchString = this.$.searchField.value;
    $.post('/api/search/' + searchString, function(res) {
      this.results = res;
      console.log(this.results);
    });
  }
});
```

The response is correct, its an array of objects. In angular I would use scope.$apply but I didn't found a solution for polymer. Please help.

Comment: How are you using `this.results`? And are you sure that the _this_ in your callback function refers to the _moviegrep-element_? In most cases you need to apply `bind(this)` to a callback function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one mistake in your code is that you're using `this` inside callback - that `this` isn't the polymer element there! So try something like following (note the use of `_THIS` variable)

```
  search: function() {
    var searchString = this.$.searchField.value;
    var _THIS = this;
    $.post('/api/search/' + searchString, function(res) {
      _THIS.results = res;
    });
```

If that toesn't help try to assign the array to the template's model directly:

```
<template repeat="{{ r in results }}" id="tmpl_results">
...
```

```
  search: function() {
    var searchString = this.$.searchField.value;
    var tmpl = this.$.tmpl_results;
    $.post('/api/search/' + searchString, function(res) {
      tmpl.model = {results:res};
    });
```